# Is an isolated point in $\mathbb{R}^d$ a limit point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I just read the definition of **limit point** and **isolated point** in the book *Real Analysis: measure theory, integration and hilbert spaces by e.m. stein and r. shakarchi*

> A point $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is a limit point of $E$ if for every $r>0$, the ball $B_{r}(x)$ contains points of $E$. ( Does it mean $B_{r}(x)\cap E \neq \emptyset ?$ )

> An isolated point of $E$ is a point $x\in E$ s.t. there exists an $r>0$ where $B_{r}(x)\cap E$ is equal to $\{x\}$

Since the definition of limit point here does not require $B_{r}(x)$ contains points of $E\backslash$$\{x\}$, then an isolated point of $E$ is a limit point of $E$ since for every $r>0$, the ball $B_{r}(x)$ contains a point $x\in E$. I was confused about that. (Or the "points" in the definition of limit point means at least two different points?)

Answer (score 4):

The way these definitions are written here, yes, it looks like isolated points become limit points.

This is, however, not the conventional definition of limit points. We usually require that $B_r(x)$ contains points of $E$ in addition to $x$ itself. With the conventional definition, isolated points are not limit points. In fact, the isolated points of $E$ are exactly the points of $E$ that are not limit points (note that also points outside $E$ can be limit points of $E$).

Comment: Thanks! But I read the book just now, and I noticed a sentence says "every point in $E$ is a limit point of $E$", is it wrong?

Comment: @YangGao: Using the definition of the book, that sentence is right (clearly every ball around a point of $E$ contains a point of $E$, namely that point itself). Using the conventional definition, the sentence is generally wrong (if $E$ has isolated points, they are not limit points according to the conventional definition).

Comment: *We usually require that* $B_r(x)$ *contains points of* $E$ *in addition to* $x$ *itself.* --- The fact that "points" is plural in the excerpt "contains points of $E$" that @Yang Gao gave might have been purposely used to imply this, but if so, I think for exposition purposes this aspect should have been made more explicit, especially given the relatively large number of [ESL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language) readers one would expect for most any non-elementary mathematics text.